# Importing Leica total station .GSI file data into ArcGIS Desktop 9.x?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, land-survey, total-station

I have a total station data file (test.gsi) that was collected with a Leica 1200.

How can I import the data to ArcGIS 9.x and plot points with the point name given by the total station observer. After importing the points i need to draw polygons around the points to define land parcels.

Comment: Do you have access to Leica's MobileMatrix?  http://www.leica-geosystems.com/en/Mobile-GIS-Data-Collection-Software-Leica-MobileMatriX_5316.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS **Survey Analyst** extension supports .gsi import

Survey Analyst imports and exports measurements and other field data from Total Positioning System (TPS) equipment using the following survey data converter formats: ASCII converter, Geodimeter converter, **GSI converter**, SDR converter, TDS coordinate converter, and TDS raw converter.

The data import utility can be extended programmatically to import additional data formats.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/surveyanalyst/common-questions.html

Which data formats can be imported into a survey project?

You can also convert points to polygons (min of 3 points) programmatically for automating land parcel creation.

Comment: mapperz thanks for the reply.... mapperz i imported the gsi file to survey database and dragged it to the arcview.. and i got the ponts.. next thing what i want to do is build land parcels from the points and also display the point labels

Comment: I would use the Cadastral Editor to create 'cadastral fabric' includes points to parcels  http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Understanding_feature_class_adjustments & http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Cadastral_fabric_source_data

Comment: Starting with ArcGIS 10.0, Survey Analyst has been [deprecated](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57455-ArcGIS-Survey-Analyst-has-been-deprecated-at-ArcGIS-9.3.1-see-Land-Record-Forum). At the moment, a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/how-can-i-get-a-total-station-raw-file-into-arcgis) has been asked on this topic seeking an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisW. Yes, while the Q is much newer, my A to **How can I get Sokkia total station .RAW file data into ArcGIS** is applicable because Copan also reads Leica .GSI data files.

Comment: @martinf I agree, and in fact I would say post your same answer here in the event the two questions are not merged.