# How can I get Sokkia total station .RAW file data into ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, land-survey, total-station

I have a .raw file from a Sokkia total station.  I want to view the data in ArcGIS and create contours from this data.  Can anyone help?  The survey analyst extension is longer supported in ArcGIS 10.1 so I'm not sure where to begin...

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as a duplicate or not. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/how-do-i-import-total-station-data-gsi-files-into-arcgis covers a different Total Station format and the answer was to use an extension no longer available. I don't know if the questions should be merged or remain separate because of the different file type and to encourage new answers/alternatives to the original given software changes.

Comment: I believe Copan (which is free) can do what you need. Please post a sample of your raw data so i can confirm. Use the "edit" button, above (between "share" and "flag") and paste it in as though it were code (it *is* code). I can give a detailed answer...

Comment: @ChrisW - Leica GSI and Nikon (Sokkia) RAW file formats are very different. I can give new, useful answers to both questions, though i'm uncertain as to whether they should be classed as duplicates or not -- probably not.

Comment: Similar Q&A: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/acceptable-traverse-field-file-syntax-and-field-file-processing-on-copan-11-11-w

Comment: @martinf I'd run across one of your past answers mentioning a conversion tool that handled a variety of formats but couldn't find it or remember the name. I also knew that Total Station formats were varied and different, just like digital camera raw files. I can see two routes - a single question titled 'Total Station file' in general (personally I favor this), or editing the two separate questions (in title) to specify maker and not just file extension (which implies but doesn't guarantee format). You should definitely give a new answer to the old question if they aren't merged.

Answer (score 4):

As you have discovered, starting with ArcGIS 10.0, Survey Analyst has been [deprecated](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/57455-ArcGIS-Survey-Analyst-has-been-deprecated-at-ArcGIS-9.3.1-see-Land-Record-Forum). The functions were split - Cadastral editor was integrated into the two higher license levels, while the Survey Editor functions are no longer supported.  However, [another extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability) called [Data Interoperability](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_the_Data_Interoperability_extension/004m00000001000000/) may allow you to read and import your file, among others. It isn't cheap if this is a one-time thing.

I am not familiar with that particular file format - is it binary or text based? If text based it may be possible to figure out a script or conversion process. If binary, it may require a different third-party software for the conversion. I went to the Sokkia site and [their software](http://www.magnet-tour.com/magnet-office.html) offers a free trial (as does the ESRI Data Interoperability extension).

Answer (score 3):

There's a free software package, [**Copan**](http://underhill.ca/software/copan-windows), that can read [several different total station data files](http://underhill.ca/software/manuals/windows/user_manual/Field%20Files.html), including Sokkia/Nikon .RAW, and *possibly* do the necessary cogo calculations to derive and save point coordinates in .CSV format. That output can, presumably, then be imported into any GIS or cogo software.

I say "possibly" because it depends on whether the traditional, *raw data*, angles-and-distances, have been recorded -- what Copan can work with directly -- or the alternative, *reduced data*, coordinates, have been recorded. (That's why i ask you to provide a file sample.)

In the latter case, Copan will present them for you still but need to do some manual editing to get them into a perfect format. As a former developer of Copan, I know it *was* on the ToDo list to accept and use coordinate input from total station files, but we never got around to it.